Fancyhdr doesn't work on first page
Fancyhdr doesn't seem to be working on the first page of my document.
My preamble:
\pdfminorversion=7 %For the inclusion of pdfs
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}

% Packages
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, dsfont, mathtools, pgfplots} % Math symbols
\usepackage{fullpage, graphicx} % Formatting
\usepackage{hyperref} % Clickable links
\usepackage{enumitem} % Enumerate options   
\usepackage{xcolor} % For the colours
\usepackage{thmtools} % Changing the QED symbol, etc.
\usepackage{caption, subcaption} % Captioning of tables and such
\usepackage{tikz-cd} % tikz
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,angles} % tikz add-ons
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\tikzset{external/force remake}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

% Formatting
\linespread{1.1}
\frenchspacing
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=purple, citecolor=blue, linkcolor=red, pdfstartview={XYZ null null 0.90}}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy} % Page style
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % no line on top of page
\renewcommand{\footruleskip}{20pt}

However, the first page number looks like this

and the rest like this (how I want):

For some reason it's way smaller only on the first page

I guess that you have \maketitle in the first page, don't you?

Yes, where should I have it?

I would guess same as egreg, but please don't make people guess, always show a small complete document that shows the problem.

\maketitle does \thispagestyle{firstpage}% this sets first page specifications

What should I do instead?

you could redefine the firstpagestyle using fancyhdr or use \thispagestyle{fancy} after \maketitle or if using amsart to submit to the AMS just live with the style choice.

You are a genius, thank you very much this was giving me a massive headache.

tell that to @egreg he's bound to agree:-)

In amsart, \maketitle does \thispagestyle{firstpage} which uses \scriptsize page number.
You could redefine the firstpagestyle using fancyhdr or use \thispagestyle{fancy} after \maketitle or if using amsart to submit to the AMS just live with the style choice.
